# Spring boot test fails with No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.DispatcherServletPath'

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a Spring Boot application which works when run, but I am getting an error when I try to do some testing with MockMVC. The error is triggered by one line in the SecurityConfig:

```
val publicUrls = arrayOf(
    "/telemetry/**",
    "/login",
    "/logout"
)

override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
    http
        .csrf().ignoringAntMatchers(*publicUrls)
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.to("status", "info")).permitAll()

        // The following line is the problem
        .requestMatchers(PathRequest.toStaticResources().atCommonLocations()).permitAll()   // <-- causes error

        .antMatchers(*publicUrls).permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/system/**").hasRole("SUPER")
        .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
    //.and()
    //.oauth2Login();
}
```

Without the line allowing access to static resources, the test works correctly. With this line in place, I get the error below (with stack trace). If I add a class implementing `DispatcherServletPath` annotated with `@Component` then I get an error `expected single matching bean but found 2:` instead.

The test code is:

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@WebAppConfiguration
@ComponentScan("com.controlj.monitor.service")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner::class)
class SampleTest {

    @MockBean
    private lateinit var mockTelemetryService: TelemetryService
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var springSecurityFilterChain: FilterChainProxy

    private lateinit var mvc: MockMvc

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        mvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(TelemetryEndpoint(mockTelemetryService))
            .apply<StandaloneMockMvcBuilder>(SecurityMockMvcConfigurers.springSecurity(springSecurityFilterChain))
            .build()
    }

   @Test
    fun testTelemetryApi() {
        val postMapping = TelemetryEndpoint::post.findAnnotation<PostMapping>()?.value?.first()
        mvc.perform(post(postMapping, "badKey", 123456)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().`is`(404))
   }
}
```

How do I get around this?

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.DispatcherServletPath' available

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.StaticListableBeanFactory.getBean(StaticListableBeanFactory.java:172)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.StubWebApplicationContext.getBean(StubWebApplicationContext.java:176)
at org.springframework.boot.security.servlet.ApplicationContextRequestMatcher.lambda$createContext$1(ApplicationContextRequestMatcher.java:95)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.StaticResourceRequest$StaticResourceRequestMatcher.initialized(StaticResourceRequest.java:140)
at org.springframework.boot.security.servlet.ApplicationContextRequestMatcher.getContext(ApplicationContextRequestMatcher.java:73)
at org.springframework.boot.security.servlet.ApplicationContextRequestMatcher.matches(ApplicationContextRequestMatcher.java:57)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.DefaultFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource.getAttributes(DefaultFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource.java:95)
at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:197)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:124)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:100)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:74)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:133)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:182)
```

Answer (score -1):

try to give your own implementation of `DispatcherServletPath` a name

```
@Component("dispatcherServlet")
public class Your_Dispatch_Servlet implements DispatcherServletPath {
}
```

Comment: As stated in my question, adding a component to satisfy this results in the error `No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.DispatcherServletPath' available: expected single matching bean but found 2:`
If I add your code with the `@Component("dispatcherServlet")` annotation I get a different error: `org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionOverrideException: Invalid bean definition with name 'dispatcherServlet' `

Answer (score -1):

For me, some tests pass or fail depending on how I run them, or if I run them together or individually — which obviously isn't ideal. But it seems the same line in my security config is causing me the problem.

I'm sure that this isn't the final fix for this, but as a workaround for now, I have replaced:

```
PathRequest.toStaticResources().atCommonLocations()
```

with:

```
new AntPathRequestMatcher("/webjars/**", "GET")
```

I am only using static resources from [WebJars](https://www.webjars.org/), so this is enough to get me past this for now. I guess the problem is actually elsewhere, though.